# Why my code don't work when I pass it to .exe?

Tags: python, opencv, windows-10, pyinstaller, python-3.10

I made a program that detects an image on the screen, I use for it the pyautogui library, when I run my program it works perfectly well, but when I pass it in executable, it does not work anymore and I have the error message below.

I am under windows 10. I have python 3.10 and pyinstaller 5.0

The error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interface.py", line 21, in <module>
    ScreenLocation = pa.locateOnScreen('module\images\location.PNG', confidence=0.7)
  File "pyautogui\__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
  File "pyautogui\__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
  File "pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 373, in locateOnScreen
  File "pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 353, in locate
  File "pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 253, in _locateAll_python
NotImplementedError: The confidence keyword argument is only available if OpenCV is installed.
```

[image]

I hope I've been clear enough, don't hesitate to ask me questions if there is any information missing to solve my problem, thank you for taking time for me, I hope we will find a solution.

Comment: Did you read the error?  You will need to modify your pyinstaller script to force OpenCV to be included.

Comment: As the error says: You are using `confidence=0.7` in your call to `pa.locateOnScreen`, but as the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) say, you need to have OpenCV installed for the `confidence` keyword to work.

Comment: How do I force pyinstaller  to include opencv  ?

Comment: I install opencv in python with pip install opencv-python,is it the wrong way ?

Comment: I tried to remove the confidence=0.7 but now the application cannot find the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pip install OpenCV and import OpenCV in your script.

Comment: I allready install opencv with pip install opencv-pyton

Comment: And import OpenCV in your script as `import cv2` , so you can use the confidence 
threshold?

Comment: yes I tried but I got another error message

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "somthing.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 110, in bootstrap
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 108, in load_first_config
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.

Comment: @Daza It is a known bug between opencv 4.5.4 and pyisntaller. https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib/issues/110 . The title is missleading, this is not only for "built from source". It happens with the packaged version of opencv 4.5.4 . You can downgrade your python to 3.9 and use the previous version of opencv.

Answer (score 0):

Its a known issue between OpenCV and Pyinstaller. For now you just need to install previous version of OpenCV 4.5.3.56

```
 pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56
```